# OPTAPLANNER: Add function of planning entities as optimization constraint

Tags: optimization, constraints, optaplanner

I want to add a function of the list of planning entities as a constraint. More specifically, each planning entity has a contribution x, and I want to implement a constraint that adds a HARD score if the sum of all the x contributions is greater than X. Something like...

```
Constraint ConstraintX(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory
            .forEach(planningEntity.class)
            .filter(planningEntity-> planningEntity.get_x())
            .sum().penalize("Sum of xs bigger than X", 
                            HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                            sum > X # what goes here???                                                
                            );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [OptaPlanner documentation on Constraint Collectors](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/constraint-streams/constraint-streams.html#constraintStreamsGroupingAndCollectors).
Specifically `ConstraintCollectors.sum(...)` does exactly what you need.